# Why Infinitity is added on reduce function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In this specific code,

```
function cakes(recipe, available) {
  return Object.keys(recipe).reduce(function(val, ingredient) {
    return Math.min(parseInt(available[ingredient] / recipe[ingredient] || 0), val)
  },Infinity);
}
```

sample function call:

```
cakes({ flour: 500, sugar: 200, eggs: 1 },{flour: 1000, sugar: 1200, eggs: 5, milk: 200 });
```

"It returns **2**".

If I remove `Infinity` in the code, It returns `NaN`.

Comment: So that the first comparison in Math.min succeeds.

Comment: The second argument is the initial value for reduce

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) takes a reduction function and a starting value. In math we usually use `0` when doing addition eg. `[].reduce((v, a) => v + a, 0) // ==> 0` while multiplication uses 1 eg. `[].reduce((v, a) => v * a, 1) // ==> 1`

If I call your code with a kake with no ingredients it will return the initial accumulator value:

```
const ingredients = { sand: 10000 };
const airCake = {};
cakes(airCake, ingredients); // ==> Infinity
```

Thus you can make infinitely many air cakes. The second you have a cake with one ingredient you don't have an infinite amount of and that you require more than 0 of you will get a number of times you can make this cake that is less than infinite and this is passed to the next ingredient. The result is the ratio of which ingredient you have the least of compared to the amount it is used.

```
const sandCake = { sand: 100 };
cakes(sandCake, ingredients); // ==> 100
```

This returns 100 because you have enough sand for 100 which is lower than Infinity.

If you don't supply a starting value to `reduce` it will use the first value in the array as the accumulator and thus you are doing this as he first iteration:

```
Math.min(parseInt(available['sugar'] / recipe['sugar'] || 0), 'flour') // => NaN
```

`Math.min` doesn't know how to interpret `flour` numerically and it immediately turns into `NaN` (Not a number). And further iterations gets this:

```
Math.min(5, Nan); // => NaN
```

All JS math function will return `NaN` if ANY value in it is `NaN`. This is kind of error handling by monads where you let the math not fail and can study the result when done that values were out of bounds. Here is an example of creating `NaN`, `Infinity` and `-Infinity` in JS:

```
 0 / 0; // => NaN
 1 / 0; // => Infinity
-1 / 0; // => -Infinity
```

If you were to find the Maximum of something where you can go below zero `-Inifinty` is a pretty good accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Its the initial value of reduce method, if you replace by a number it will be the max number in your function.

```js
function cakes(recipe, available) {
  return Object.keys(recipe).reduce(function(val, ingredient) {
    return Math.min(parseInt(available[ingredient] / recipe[ingredient] || 0), val)
  },10000);
}
```